# Tough integral with many radicals

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am completed baffled with this integral

$$\int\left[\dfrac{1}{x^{1/3}+x^{1/4}}+\dfrac{\ln(1+x^{1/6})}{x^{1/3}+x^{1/2}}\right]\mathrm dx$$

Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: In
$$
\int\frac{\ln(1+x^{1/6})}{x^{1/3}+x^{1/2}}\;dx ,
$$
substitution $y=1+x^{1/6}$ does a lot for you.

In
$$
\int\frac{1}{x^{1/3}+x^{1/4}}\;dx
$$
try $y=x^{1/12}$.

Comment: But I am not able to express the denominator in terms of dy in the first integral

Comment: $x=(y-1)^6$, so $dx = \cdots$.